# Raster to matrix in R returns NA,Rayshader

Tags: r, matrix, rayshader, elevatr

So i am downloading the elevation data for a shapefile, which i have saved in my pc. But for some reason. I use this shapefile to download the elevation data in R using elevatr package. To plot this elevation data in raysahder,we need this to be converted into a matrix form but somehow all i get back is NAs.
Heres the code:

```
arw = readOGR("Shape file/american water/American_River_Watershed.shp")
dem_arw =elevatr::get_elev_raster(arw,z = 10,clip = "location")
raster_to_matrix(dem_arw)
```

The output i get is NAs only or simple matrix number entries like:
[image: Nas or simple entries]

I have tried other shapefiles too and updating the Rayshader package too but still i get this. This worked almost a week ago but now all of a sudden it doesn't.
Please any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hello! Please share a dput() of your data so others can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @SantiagoCapobianco,i think the NAs are there for every raster layer while being converted to a matrix. I was checking the head and the tail of the matrix,both happened to be NAs,but there are values in between the matrix. So i used rayshaders sphere_shade() function to plot the matrix,and it worked... Guess the NAs are there but we don't need to mess with them. Thanks for the reply though